# AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'scope' when using legacy Developer Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I was trying to implement AAD in my APIM instance based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2). Unfortunately when it came down to Developer console, right after I picked Authorization code as the Authorization method a popup showed up and showed me the following error:

```
AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'scope'.
```

It failed on `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Directory (tenant) ID
}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client id}&redirect_uri=https://{my-apim-instance}/docs/services/{authorization method}/console/oauth2/authorizationcode/callback&state={state}`.

Since all of this is part of Azure Portal (at this point the legacy Developer Portal) I do not fill the scope parameter. How can you set that property? Or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using **V2** endpoints, you need to use the scope you created for the backend-app in the **Default scope** field.

[image]

You can find the scope from your [webapi application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#register-an-application-in-azure-ad-to-represent-the-api).

[image]

Comment: That solved the problem :-) It also introduced another one, but I think the new one should be easier to solve :-) Thank you.